# Prove that every equation of degree $n$ in $x$ has $n$ roots and no more.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Prove that every equation of degree $n$ in $x$ has $n$ roots and no more.

My Attempt:

Let us suppose $f(x)=0$ where
$$f(x)=a_0 x^n + a_1 x^{n-1}+.....+a_{n-1} x+a_n$$

According to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, the equation $f(x)=0$ has a root, real or complex. Let this root be $\alpha_1$; then by the Factor Theorem, $x-\alpha_1$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

So, how do I proceed from here?

Comment: Write $f(x)=\left(x-\alpha_1\right)g\left(x\right)$, and proceed by induction.

Comment: I see no reason to downvote.

Comment: @Guy, Please elaborate more.

Comment: @ajotatxe: Not that I care personally but I could easily imagine someone getting angry at someone using a famous persons name and picture for their account.

Comment: Use induction on $\deg f$. If $\deg f=0$, it is trivial. Otherwise, as you wrote, there is a root $\alpha_1$, hence we may write $f(x)=\left(x-\alpha_1\right)g(x)$. Now use the induction hypothesis on $g$ to conclude.

Comment: Equation of degree $n$ = polynomial? Solutions in $\mathbb{C}$? Different roots?

Answer (score 2):

We have $f(\alpha_1)=0$. Then we can write $f(x) = (x-\alpha_1)g(x)\quad$ where $g(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $n-1$.

So, $g(x)$ must have a root $\alpha_2$. Then we can write $f(x) =(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)h(x)$ where $h(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $n-2$ etc...

In general we have a proposition that a polynomial $f(x)$ with degree $n$ has $n$ roots for $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.

So for $n=1:$

$f(x) = a_1x +a_0=0\implies x=-\frac{a_0}{a_1}$ is the only root. So true for $n=1$.

Assume true for $n$. Now we must prove true $n+1:$

Let $q(x)$ have degree $n+1$. So by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, there exists a root of $q(x)$ which we will call $\alpha_1$. Then we can write $q(x) = (x-\alpha_1)f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is some polynomial with degree $n$. From our inductive assumption, we have that $f(x)$ has $n$ roots. Therefore $q(x)$ has $n+1$ roots as required. Hence our statement holds $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$

Answer (score 0):

By induction over $n$:

If $n=0$ then $f \in F^\times$ and $f(\alpha)=f\neq 0$ for every $\alpha \in F$.
That is $f$ has no roots in $F$.

Suppose $n>0:$

Suppose the claim is true for every polynomial of degree $n-1$.

If $f$ has not roots in $F$, we're done.

Else, it has root $\alpha \in F$, so $f=(X-\alpha)g,\ $ for some $g\in F[X]$ of degree $n-1$.

By induction hypothesis, $g$ has at most $n-1$ different roots in $F$.

It is easy to see that the roots of $f$ are exactly the roots of $g$ and $\alpha$.

Hence, $f$ has at most $n$ different roots in $F$

Comment: what is $F$ , what have you assumed it?

Comment: @AlbertEinstein $F$ is a field.